# How to get tuple of values out of map given a tuple of keys in boost::hana?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-hana

I know I can get a *single* value from `boost::hana::map` using the `operator[]`. But I found it surprisingly difficult to "vectorise it": get multiple values from tuple of multiple keys.

Suppose we have a hana::map `the_map`:

```
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include <boost/hana/string.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/map.hpp>
#include <string>
namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

auto the_map = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key1"_s, std::string("value1")),
    hana::make_pair("key2"_s, int(42)),
    hana::make_pair("key3"_s, std::string("value3")),
    hana::make_pair("key4"_s, float(3.14)),
    hana::make_pair("key5"_s, std::string("value5"))
);
```

Eventually I want to unpack the values of this map into a function call. Because C++ pass parameters by position (not by name), I need to get a tuple of values with the specific order. `hana::map` does not guarantee the order of the entries, so I need to extract them by keys, effectively implementing something in the direction of the named tuple to achieve something similar to passing function arguments by name.

So suppose I have a function `myfun` and a compile-time list of keys:

```
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>

void myfun(std::string par1, int par2, std::string par3, float par4, std::string par5) {
    //...
}

constexpr auto the_keys = hana::make_tuple("key1"_s, "key2"_s, "key3"_s, "key4"_s, "key5"_s);
```

What I want is to somehow get a tuple of values out of `the_map` given the keys `the_keys`, so I could call the function with `int main() {hana::unpack(the_items, myfun);}`.

The best I made so far is the following failing C++ code:

```
#include <boost/hana/at_key.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/fold_left.hpp>

template<typename T, typename U>
auto accessor(U sequence, T key) {
    static_assert(hana::Foldable<U>::value);
    return hana::insert(sequence, 0_c, ms[key]);
}

auto the_items_manually=accessor(accessor(accessor(hana::make_tuple(), "key1"_s), "key2"_s), "key3"_s); //this works
auto the_items = hana::fold_left(keys, hana::make_tuple(), accessor); //compile error
```

The last line produces an error.

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::hana::fold_left_t) (const boost::hana::tuple<boost::hana::string<'k', 'e', 'y', '1'>, boost::hana::string<'k', 'e', 'y', '2'>, boost::hana::string<'k', 'e', 'y', '3'>, boost::hana::string<'k', 'e', 'y', '4'>, boost::hana::string<'k', 'e', 'y', '5'> >&, boost::hana::tuple<>, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
     auto the_items = hana::fold_left(keys, hana::make_tuple(), accessor);
```

My GCC 7.3.0 C++14 compiler also notes, that

```
boost/hana/fold_left.hpp:26:30: note: candidate: template<class Xs, class State, class F> constexpr decltype(auto) boost::hana::fold_left_t::operator()(Xs&&, State&&, F&&) const
     constexpr decltype(auto) fold_left_t::operator()(Xs&& xs, State&& state, F&& f) const {
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

and

```
boost/hana/fold_left.hpp:26:30: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/Adama-docs/Adam/MyDocs/praca/IMGW/repos/all5/eulag-verification/simple_test/test5.cpp:67:72: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘F’
     auto the_items = hana::fold_left(keys, hana::make_tuple(), accessor);
                                                                        ^
```

I understand, that the error wants me to explicitely type in a proper type of something as a template argument. Well, whatever it may be, the point of Hana usability is not to have to type the types, so I think I need to have a different approach. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `accessor` here given to `hana::fold_left` must be a lambda or a function object, otherwise I think it would have worked. (It doesn't support function pointers)

For better compile-time performance, [`hana::unpack`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Foldable.html#ga7b0c23944364ce61136e10b978ae2170) is better than `hana::fold_left` when its possible since it doesn't have to create an intermediate object for every element in the list.

Here is an example using a high order function that captures the map:

```cpp
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

int main() {
  auto get_values = [](auto const& map) {
    return [&](auto const& ...key) {
      return hana::make_tuple(map[key]...);
    };
  };

  auto myfun = [](std::string par1, int par2, std::string par3, float par4, std::string par5) {
    std::cout << par1 << '\n'
              << par2 << '\n'
              << par3 << '\n'
              << par4 << '\n'
              << par5 << '\n'
              ;
  };

  auto the_map = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key1"_s, std::string("value1")),
    hana::make_pair("key2"_s, int(42)),
    hana::make_pair("key3"_s, std::string("value3")),
    hana::make_pair("key4"_s, float(3.14)),
    hana::make_pair("key5"_s, std::string("value5"))
  );

  constexpr auto the_keys = hana::make_tuple("key1"_s, "key2"_s, "key3"_s, "key4"_s, "key5"_s);

  auto values = hana::unpack(the_keys, get_values(the_map));
  hana::unpack(values, myfun);
}
```

You may also want to check out [Boost.Hof](http://boost-hof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc/) for tools to lift raw functions to objects and other neat point-free programming stuffs.

Comment: It is a great solution! And thank you for the optimization tip. The way the parameter pack is handled in C++ and Hana is really great. I still need a little time to get accustomed to it.